# Making install script on linux mint

Tags: python, linux, bash

I made a program that turns on my Logitech G9 LED lights whenever I have an unread message in slack. I'm trying to made the program installable with a script but I'm unfamiliar with where things should go. Right now, the program relies on [g9led](http://als.regnet.cz/logitech-g9-linux-led-color.html) and python to work. If I make an install script, where is the best place to move the executables? `/usr/bin` ?

My install script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /tmp
wget http://als.regnet.cz/data/g9led.c
gcc g9led.c -o g9led -lusb
rm g9led.c
mv g9led /usr/bin/g9led
mv unread_msg_monitor.py /usr/bin/unread_msg_monitor.py
sed -i ". /home/papes1ns/.virtualenvs/unread/bin/activate && python /home/papes1ns/Projects/hes_slack_integration/unread.py &" /etc/rc.local
echo "finished"
exit 0
```

https://github.com/papes1ns/slack_unread_msg_monitor/blob/master/unread_msg_monitor.py

Comment: Install scripts usually don't live anywhere, they are meant to be downloaded, executed and removed. I usually place mine under /tmp just so they don't clutter down my installation. Are you intending to use this as part of a iso? Or why would you place it in $PATH?

Comment: Correct, I intend to use the install file as you just described. I have two other executables: g9led (c program) and unread_msg_monitor.py (python program). What I'm asking is where should these files live when they are called from `rc.local` on startup. I have them chilling in my home folder now.

Comment: The installed scripts (not the installer itself) should live in /usr/bin if you ask me. But these are a matter of preference and the community finds new places for things to live every other year. Such as /opt/ or /var/. I'm old school and prefer /usr/bin

Comment: Based on my research, I concluded that /usr/bin made the most sense. This is my first time writing an installable and was wondering if there was conventions to follow, which doesn't appear to be the case. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wrong with leaving your executables (somewhere) in your home folder.

But as far as automating your softwares, instead of `/etc/rc.local`, consider using an init scheme to control your services and have them start on bootup.

For example, if you have [runit](http://smarden.org/runit/) on your system (sudo apt-get install runit), you'd create 2 scripts, say `g9monitor.runit`:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /home/papes1ns
exec chpst -upapes1ns:papes1ns python unread_msg_monitor.py
```

and `g9led.runit`:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /home/papes1ns
exec chpst -upapes1ns:papes1ns g9led
```

Then copy above files to directories in `/etc/sv/`:

```
sudo mkdir -p /etc/sv/g9monitor /etc/sv/g9led
sudo cp g9monitor.runit /etc/sv/g9monitor/run
sudo cp g9led.runit /etc/sv/g9led/run
```

Make them executable, and create soft links in `/etc/service`:

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/sv/g9monitor/run /etc/sv/g9led/run
sudo ln -sf /etc/sv/g9monitor /etc/service/g9monitor
sudo ln -sf /etc/sv/g9led /etc/service/g9led
```

Once the links are made, the services should start. You can then control them via `sv` commands:

```
sudo sv status g9monitor
sudo sv down g9led
sudo sv up g9led
```

To disable them, remove the links:

```
sudo rm -f /etc/service/g9monitor
sudo rm -f /etc/service/g9led
```